# Is there a way to apply dense_rank in Hibernate Criteria API?

Tags: sql, hibernate-criteria

SQL comes with a dense_rank() function. Is there a way to apply dense_rank in Hibernate Criteria API?

Answer (score 1):

I realise there Hibernate's Criteria API does not support window functions. I had to write an algorithm for ranking and applied it to the extracted records.